# Use KFolds to split dataframe: I want the rows to be split but the columns are getting split instead

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-fold

I have a 466 x 1025 dataframe. 1024 variables and the target make up the columns. I am using a random forest regression on the data set, and am trying to use folds to get more consistent predictions. My target is splitting correctly, but when applied to the data, the columns are getting split instead of the rows. I am getting training data of 466 x 372 and test data of 466 x 94. I need training data of 372 x 1024 and test data of 94 x 1024. How do I fix this? Note: it does work correctly when I use train_test_split()

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

#read the data files, verify types
df = pd.read_csv('./allMolecules.csv')   

#the data frame is ready, now it's time for the random forest. 
#split data into train and test
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1), finalDF['Target'],test_size=0.2)
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
output = model.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
score = model.score(xTest,yTest)
print('Model Settings:\n{0}\n'.format(output))
print('R2: {0}'.format(score))

folds = KFold(n_splits=5)
scores = []
data = finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1)
for trainIndex, testIndex in folds.split(finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1)):
    print(trainIndex, testIndex)
    xTrain = data[trainIndex]
    xTest = (finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1))[testIndex]
    yTrain = finalDF['Target'][trainIndex]
    yTest = finalDF['Target'][testIndex]
    print('\n\n{0}\n\n{1}\n\n{2}\n\n{3}'.format(xTrain,xTest,yTrain,yTest))
    output = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    scores.append(model.score(xTest, yTest))

print(scores)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be getting the indexing wrong at some point. `KFold` only splits on the first axis. 
Try keeping it simpler, split into `X` and `y` before indexing from the results of `folds.split`, and work with arrays instead:

```
X = finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1).values
y = finalDF.target.values
for trainIndex, testIndex in folds.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in use pandas dataframe, then the solution to your problems look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X = [[ 0.87, -1.34,  0.31, 0],
     [-2.79, -0.02, -0.85, 1],
     [-1.34, -0.48, -2.55, 0],
     [ 1.92,  1.48,  0.65, 1]]

finalDF = pd.DataFrame(X * 20, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'Target'])


folds = KFold(n_splits=5)
scores = []
for trainIndex, testIndex in folds.split(finalDF.drop(['Target'], axis=1)):
    # print(trainIndex, testIndex)
    xTrain = finalDF.loc[trainIndex, :]
    xTest = finalDF.loc[testIndex, :]
    print(xTrain.shape, xTest.shape)
```

For this example, you will get as output (in the print)

```
(64, 4) (16, 4)
(64, 4) (16, 4)
(64, 4) (16, 4)
(64, 4) (16, 4)
(64, 4) (16, 4)
```

Your problem was when you try to access to a Dataframe is better to specify index or columns access and the **loc** method is a good option to do that. In the case of **y** you get a good result because you transform to a **pd.Series** before indexing.

Hope this helps!